# Coffescript 2 output es6 code. Using webpack and coffee-loader, will it automatically transpiled to ES5 code?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, coffeescript

Coffescript 2 is out already. It now produces es6 code.
Using webpack and coffee-loader, will it automatically be transpiled to ES5 code?

Comment: What has your research turned up? What configuration settings have you found that would relate? [Their documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#transpilation) says you'll need to transpile, so that leads you to your Webpack/coffee-loader config, presumably?

Comment: If we use coffeescript 2 compiler with --transpile flag it will be compiled to es6 code, then transpiled to es5 code with the help of babel. That is what i get when experimenting with a node.js app.

Comment: I am not sure if coffeescript is compiled to es5 when using it with nuxt, a vue js framework. It has its own build configuration powered by webpack. What i did is extending the webpack config. I am not sure how to check if its already es5 in the compiled code. But looks like there is no more es6 keyword there, such as 'import' and 'export default'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won’t automatically output ES5, no. You either need to use the `transpile` option in `coffee-loader` or pipe `coffee-loader`’s output to a transpiler like Babel.

`webpack.config.js` per https://github.com/webpack-contrib/coffee-loader#transpile:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.coffee$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'coffee-loader',
            options: { 
              transpile: {
                presets: ['env']
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```